# Naming configurable parameter for downstream module to handle latency

Tags: naming

I'm struggling to find a good name for a configurable parameter in a testbench.

The parameter is used to control how many downstream requests can be queued until we stall the upstream module.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

How about **clearanceNum** ?

Clearance is mean official authorization for something to proceed ...